# How to get specific attributes from array from hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, key-value

I have an array of hash that needs to be sorted by `imp` and I want to get the specific attribute out of it.

```
array_of_hash is 
[
  {
      :id => "9",
      :subsystem => "xyz",
      :component => "xyz",
      :imp => "1",
      :old_serial => "55q",
      :current_serial => nil,
      :old_num => "same",
      :current_num => nil,
      :acceptable_nums => [
         "asdf",
         "qwer",
         "zxcv",
         "poiu"
    ]
},
 {
     :id => "10",
     :subsystem => "xyz",
     :component => "xyz",
     :imp => "4",
     :old_serial => "56t",
     :current_serial => nil,
     :old_num => "same",
     :current_num => nil,
     :acceptable_nums => [
         "asdf",
         "qwer",
         "zxcv",
         "poiu"
    ]
},
{
      :id => "11",
      :subsystem => "xyz",
      :component => "xyz",
      :imp => "3",
      :old_serial => "57s",
      :current_serial => nil,
      :old_num => "same",
      :current_num => nil,
      :acceptable_nums => [
        "asdf",
        "qwer",
        "zxcv",
        "poiu"
    ]
},
  {
     :id => "14",
     :subsystem => "xyz",
     :component => "xyz",
     :imp => "2",
     :old_serial => "58r",
     :current_serial => nil,
     :old_num => "same",
     :current_num => nil,
     :acceptable_nums => [
        "asdf",
        "qwer",
        "zxcv",
        "poiu"
    ]
}
]
```

First step, sorting

```
array_of_hash.sort_by {|hash| hash[:imp].to_i}
```

Then i want specific attribute

**Desired output** with some condition

```
{
      :imp => "1-4",  #It should be range
      :old_serial => "55q,56r,57s,58t",  #old_serial number should be separated with comma respectively 
      :old_num => "same",
      :acceptable_nums => [
         "asdf",
         "qwer",
         "zxcv",
         "poiu"
    ]
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to do this.

Comment: Why did imp 1 and imp 4 get put into one object?  What's the logic around that.

Comment: Actually i want to make it DRY. So i m merging `1,2,3,4` and making range `1-4`

Comment: only `imp` and `older_serial` are concatenated?  What about `old_num` and `acceptable_nums`

Comment: @Anthony: They're the same.

Comment: Yes they are the same.

Comment: In the example they are but I just wanted to know if they weren't the same, what the expectation is.

Comment: @Anthony if they weren't same then `old_num` will be same as `older_serial` and `acceptable_nums` will be collection of array.

Comment: For reasons that should be obvious, questions are not to be changed after answers have been posted. Also, when you give an example, all inputs should be valid Ruby objects (as you had before), so no `[1]`, `[2]`, etc , and a variable should be assigned to each. That allows readers to cut-and-paste and reference the variables without having to define then

Comment: Your `array_of_hash` is not a valid Ruby array, it's the output of an `inspect`. Please remove that and provide a proper array-of-hashes definition. See "[mcve]" and the linked page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a combination of `sort_by`, `group_by` and `map` :

```
p array_of_hash.sort_by { |h| h[:imp] }
               .group_by{ |h| h.values_at(:acceptable_nums, :old_num) }
               .map{ |(old_num, nums), hashes|
  {
    imp: hashes.map{ |h| h[:imp].to_i },
    old_serial: hashes.map{ |h| h[:old_serial] }.join(','),
    old_num: old_num,
    acceptable_nums: nums
  }
}
# [{:imp=>[1, 2, 3, 4], :old_serial=>"55q,58r,57s,56t", :old_num=>["asdf", "qwer", "zxcv", "poiu"], :acceptable_nums=>"same"}]
```

The output is an array of hashes. There will be one hash for each unique pair of `old_num` and `acceptable_nums`. In your example, all the hashes had this same pair, so only one hash is outputted.

As for the desired conversion from `[1,2,3,4]` to `"1-4"`, the documentation for [`slice_when`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) does just that :

```
a = [1,2,4,9,10,11,12,15,16,19,20,21]
b = a.slice_when {|i, j| i+1 != j }
p b.to_a #=> [[1, 2], [4], [9, 10, 11, 12], [15, 16], [19, 20, 21]]
c = b.map {|a| a.length < 3 ? a : "#{a.first}-#{a.last}" }
p c #=> [[1, 2], [4], "9-12", [15, 16], "19-21"]
d = c.join(",")
p d #=> "1,2,4,9-12,15,16,19-21"
```

Comment: Thank you. Will this works if the hashes are the active record  object? because i am getting `NoMethodError: undefined method `values_at' for ` #<Subsitute:0x0000000901fd70>

Comment: @Kavincat: Before you write hash in the title, in your question, in your variables and in your data structure, it might be a good idea to make sure you're really working with hashes.

Comment: @Kavincat: you might want to try : `.group_by{ |substitute| [substitute.acceptable_nums, substitute.old_num]}` But it's hard to say since you mention ActiveRecord for the first time in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
imps, old_serials = array_of_hash.map { |h| [h[:imp], h[:old_serial]] }.
                                  sort_by(&:first).
                                  transpose
  #=> [["1", "2", "3", "4"], ["55q", "58r", "57s", "56t"]]

{ imp: "%d-%d" % imps.map(&:to_i).minmax, old_serial: old_serials.join(',') }.
  merge(array_of_hash.first.select { |k,_| [:old_num, :acceptable_nums].include?(k) })
  #=> {:imp=>"1-4", :old_serial=>"55q,58r,57s,56t", :old_num=>"same",
  #    :acceptable_nums=>["asdf", "qwer", "zxcv", "poiu"]}
```

Note

```
array_of_hash.first.select { |k,_| [:old_num, :acceptable_nums].include?(k) }
  # => {:old_num=>"same", :acceptable_nums=>["asdf", "qwer", "zxcv", "poiu"]}
```

Comment: Plot twist : apparently, `array_of_hash` isn't an array of hashes. :-/

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit easier to read if you break this up in steps.

```
old_serial_numbers = array_of_hash.collect {|h| h[:old_serial]}.join(',')
reject_hash_keys = [:old_serial, :id, :subsystem, :component, :current_num, :current_serial]

clean_hash = array_of_hash.map do |hash| 
  hash.reject! {|k| reject_hash_keys.include? k }
  hash.merge(old_serial: old_serial_numbers)
end

clean_hash.sort_by {|hash| hash[:imp].to_i}
```